# non-commutative algebraic structure with 16 elements, need help categorizing it and finding a representation

Tags: abstract-algebra, binary-operations, magma

We have an abstract algebraic structure with the following multiplication table, has anyone seen this structure before and can anyone give it a proper name and a simple (possibly matrix) representation? In the table a clear 4 commutative sub-structure is visible (connected to quaternions most likely) and a 8 non-commutative sub-structure is also visible.

[image: Multiplication table]

Comment: As given, it is just a monoid. What is the additive structure?

Comment: My bad, my terminology is rusty, I corrected it.

Comment: What is a "4 commutative substructure"?

Comment: In the image there are several places where it looks like you've used a capital $i$ which is (to me) indiscernible from lowercase $L$.  That's kind of a mean trick :) Can you please clarify?  Ideally this would be better presented in a $\LaTeX$ table.

Comment: I expect that the table has errors on the top row around e-h, because in all other respects element $a$ seems to be the identity element. Every element has order 2. The whole structure looks similar to $Z_2^4$ where the four generators are non-commutative. Equivalently, if $K_4=Z_2^2$ is the [Klein four-group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_four-group), this looks like $K_4^2$.

Comment: I corrected my mistakes and changed letters to capitals for better visibility.